# Changing JSON object array in Javascript from "Apple and Orange" to "Apple" "Orange"

Tags: javascript, json

Have the following JSON object which is being accessed from an external json source:

```
[
    {
        "Veg": "Potato",
        "Fruit": "Apple and Orange"
    },
    {
        "Veg": "Pumpkin",
        "Fruit": "Orange and Orange"
    },
    {
        "Veg": "Potato",
        "Fruit": "Banana"
    },
    {
        "Veg": "Onion",
        "Fruit": "Mango and Orange"
    }
]
```

Need help trying to change the fruit section. At present it is Fruit A 'and' Fruit B. I need to remove the 'and' and separate the fruits.

This is the output I am trying to achieve.

```
[
{
    "Veg": "Potato",
    "Fruit": [
        "Orange",
        "Apple"      
        ]
},
{
    "Veg": "Pumpkin",
    "Fruit": [
        "Orange",
        "Orange"
    ]   
},
{
    "Fruit": [
        "Banana"            
        ]
      },
{
    "Veg": "Onion",
    "Fruit": [
        "Mango",
        "Orange"      
        ]
}
]
```

I have tried to achieve this by using split. The split however is now creating new instead of adding.

```
var food = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
for(let i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
let foodSplit = food[i].Fruit.split(' and ');
    if(foodSplit.length > 0){
   food[i].Fruit1 = foodSplit[0];
   food[i].Fruit2 = foodSplit[1];   
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is valid JSON: `{"Fruit": "Apple" "Orange"}`. Do you possibly want it within a list like `{"Fruit": ["Apple", "Orange"]}`?

Comment: Yes. Good pick up. I was writing into stackoverflow and should have check this better prior to posting. I have updated the code.

Comment: Just replace the existing property. `food[i].Fruit = food[i].Fruit.split(" and ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making changes directly to the `food` objects, create a new array with the `Fruit` values mapped to arrays by splitting on `" and "` and the rest of the properties mapped directly

```js
const response = {
  responseText: `[{"Veg":"Potato","Fruit":"Apple and Orange"},{"Veg":"Pumpkin","Fruit":"Orange and Orange"},{"Veg":"Potato","Fruit":"Banana"},{"Veg":"Onion","Fruit":"Mango and Orange"}]`
}

const food = JSON.parse(response.responseText)

const mapped = food.map(({ Fruit, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  Fruit: Fruit.split(" and "),
}))

console.log(mapped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```